# rows not saving in pagination for jquery datatables table with multiple row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I was able to successfully implement `Datatables` using the `jQuery` library. The problem is that when i click on page 2 in the pagination area it acts fine however when I go back to page 1 the records i selected are no longer selected.

Here is what it's supposed to do: [datatables select row example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html)

I updated my datatables to version: 1.10.15

Here is my call to handle the click event:

```
$("#datatable_users tbody").on("click","tr",function(){$(this).toggleClass("selected");});
```

Here is my code for creating the DataTable:

```
 $("#datatable_'.$ref.'").dataTable({
       "iDisplayLength": '.$itemlimit.',
       "language": {
               "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/English.json"
       },
                                "processing": true,
                                "serverSide": true,
                                "ajax": { // define ajax settings
                                    "url": \''.Pluto::registry('web_base_uri').'service/datatable?req=1&ref='.$ref.'\',
                                    "data": function(data) {
                                       var datafilter= $("form#JqueryDataTableFormFilter_'.$ref.'").serializeControls();
                                       $.each(datafilter, function(key, value) {
                                            data[key] = value;
                                        });
                                       //console.log(datafilter);
                                    }
                                },
                                "orderCellsTop": true,
                                "dom": "Bfrtip",
                                 buttons: [
                                    {
                                        "text": "'.$search_label.'",
                                        "className":"btn btn-default BtnjQueryDataTableFilter",
                                        "action": function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                            dt.ajax.reload();
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
```

Comment: The example is using static html table however in your case it's server side processing, with server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering etc actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server. As such, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being made to get the required data.

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar OK than is there a way to accomplish this using server side processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in server side processing the DataTable gets redrawn when you paginate so you need to keep track of what all was selected before clicking the next page and manually highlight the selected rows after each page click.

Here's an exact same working example featured on their website.

> https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do I get the id into the table row?

Comment: Shouldn't it be DT_RowId anyways?